# Counting number of lines in Text file excluding comments and new Lines in java

Tags: java, text-files, bufferedreader

Am Trying to read text file and  count the number of lines excluding multi-lines "     /    *  *    /     " comments and one  line comments "     // " from the counts and finding in the text file all the methods "myMethod    (    )    {    } "
and printing them out and the total number of methods found in the text file. The Text File Will be added during execution of the java program ex:" java MyCountLine  C:\myFolder\myText.txt ".
  I can't figure out any way to get the methods from the text file.
So Here is My code :

```
import java.io.*;

public class LineCountss {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    File inFile = null;

    if (0 < args.length) {
        // text file will be passed during run time
        inFile = new File(args[0]);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Cant Find The File Specified : " + inFile);
    }

    BufferedReader br = null;

    String sCurrentLine = null;

    String func = null;

    int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, k = 0;

    try {

        // passing the text file location for FileReader.

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inFile));

        // Looping through the text file

        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

            // avoid multi-line comments and one line comments and new
            // lines.

            if ((sCurrentLine.startsWith("/*") && sCurrentLine
                    .endsWith("*/"))
                    || sCurrentLine.startsWith("//")
                    || sCurrentLine.isEmpty()
                    || (sCurrentLine.trim().matches("[{};]+"))) {

                // count the number of comment lines and new lines to
                // exclude it from count.

                b++;

                // Getting any function in the text file that start and end
                // with ().

            } else if (sCurrentLine.contains("\\(\\)\\{")) {

                func = sCurrentLine.trim();

                // printing the functions/methods

                System.out.println(func);

                // counting the number of functions/ methods found

                k++;

            } else {

                // printing the text file just for checking

                System.out.println(sCurrentLine);

                // count the total number of lines

                a++;

            }

        }

        // excluding the number of lines that has comments and new lines

        c = a - b;

        // printing the number of lines excluding comments and new lines

        System.out.println("Number of Lines are : " + c);

        // printing the number of lines of the functions/method found inside
        // the text file.

        System.out.println("Number of Functions are : " + k);

    }

    catch (IOException e) {

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    }

    finally {

        try {

            // close bufferReader

            if (br != null) {

                br.close();

            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {

            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());

        }

      }

    }
}
```

Comment: Next time use code block, not citation.

Comment: @Kuba Rakoczy  Thanx a lot bro. Appreciate your editing.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to use `String.contains()` with regex. You can try this instead:

```
sCurrentLine.matches("[^()]+\\([^()]*\\)\\s*\\{?")
```

You should probably exclude keywords as well (so they are not treated as a function):

```
!sCurrentLine.matches("\\s*(if|switch|for|while|catch)\\s*\\(.+\\)")
```

Comment: Rakozy Really Thank you. one more thing I cant find any way to exclude the other key words such as "while()" "for()" "cathc".
any Idea to take them out.

Comment: I've fixed the answer, so it excludes the keywords you mentioned.

Comment: Rakozy  I excluded it using contains("for) || contains("while") and so on. But am getting new problem. the line for excluding the multi-line comments is not working here is my code 
 if ((sCurrentLine.startsWith("/*") && sCurrentLine.endsWith("*/")) || sCurrentLine.startsWith("//")  ||  sCurrentLine.isEmpty()  ||(sCurrentLine.trim

().matches("[{};\n]+"))){
                 //count the number of comment lines and new lines to exclude it from count.
                 b++;